# Hyper-v broke Direct Access connection (on the host)

Tags: networking, hyper-v, direct-access

As soon as I enabled the Hyper-V feature on my Windows 10 laptop, my Direct Access connectivity stopped to work.

Disabling the feature restored the ability to connect.

Especially, I can't connect to RDP session, but I can ping remote servers.

How to troubleshot that ?

As a clue, when Hyper-V is enabled, and when I try to connect to a RDP server, I got error regarding NLA :

```
No authority could be contacted for authentication.
(0x80090311)
```

EventId : 40960

I suspect something got wrong with routing, when local hyper vcard are active.

Comment: When you set up Hyper-V, you're moving the host OS into a VM, which will change your hardware IDs.  Also, if you've set up a virtual switch, your MAC address will be changed.  It's possible that your DirectAccess connection requires your unique MAC.

Comment: No, I didn't move the host to a VM. I just enabled the role in W10 roles and feature windows. I even didn't create a single VM. Just enabling the role broke the network.

Comment: I understand, but when you enable Hyper-V, the host OS moves to the "parent partition" and is no longer directly on the hardware, it's above it, it's a special VM.  Hyper-V is a bare metal (type 1 hypervisor), it's not like VirtualBox.  Hyper-V will generally move your network settings over to the new virtual switch, but it doesn't always happen and your MAC address can change.

Comment: Ok I get you now. Thanks for having learned something ;). Anyways, the DA rules are bound to computer account (applied through a GPO). There's no MAC filtering